# How do I write this symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a way to write this cool symbol in LaTeX:

[image: cool symbol]

I couldn't find online an explanation on how to create it, so I would be glad if you could help me with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thanks! This site seems very useful!

Comment: ...`$\bowtie$`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's obtained using the `\bowtie` command.

Comment: Thanks! It does a weird "blob" in the middle. Any way to remove it? (without squishing the sides like the `wasysym` package)?

Comment: Load the `mnsymbol` package.