# What is the latex symbol for something that look like a horizontal hourglass?

Tags: symbols

The symbol looks like the one between $c_i x_i$ and $d$ in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Let's see... try [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara/) yourself first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write this symbol in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605921/how-do-i-write-this-symbol-in-latex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s ⋈ (U+22C8), called `\bowtie` in `unicode-math` and several other packages.  It’s a join operator in relational algebra.